# How to find the value entered is masked or not ins selenium RC?

Tags: selenium-rc

I have usename and password field. once password is entered, i should verify that the entered password is getting masked or not.

Is there anyway to verify this in selenium - RC?

Thanks
Chandra

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Nope.  That's a visual-presentation thing, not a DOM-accessible attribute.